# Should I write one father class for all menu service or should I separate the big menu service to three different menu services class?

Tags: java, service, interface, model, extends

I have an exercise requires me to write a service to management menu.

The requirement like this:
Food menu includes: breakfast menu, lunch menu, dinner menu.
The three menu haves list menu item( name, price, description, image). Write CRUD operation for food menu.

At first, I separate completely three types of food menu to each service and write service for each food menu:

**My model ( at first):**

Food Menu model:

```
public class FoodMenu{
    private BreakfastMenu breakfastMenu;
    private DinnerMenu dinnerMenu;
    private LunchMenu lunchMenu;

    public FoodMenu(BreakfastMenu breakfastMenu, DinnerMenu dinnerMenu, LunchMenu lunchMenu){
        this.breakfastMenu = breakfastMenu;
        this.dinnerMenu = dinnerMenu;
        this.lunchMenu = lunchMenu;
    }
```

Breakfast Menu model:

```
public class BreakfastMenu {
    private List<MenuItem> menuItemList;
    public BreakfastMenu(List<MenuItem> menuItemList){
        this.menuItemList = menuItemList;
    }
}
```

Dinner Menu model:

```
public class DinnerMenu {
    public DinnerMenu(){}
    private List<MenuItem> menuItemList;

    public DinnerMenu(List<MenuItem> menuItemList){
        this.menuItemList = menuItemList;
    }
}
```

Lunch Menu model:

```
public class LunchMenu {
    private List<MenuItem> menuItemList;
    public LunchMenu(List<MenuItem> menuItemList){
        this.menuItemList = menuItemList;
    }
    public LunchMenu(){}
}
```

**My Service( at first):**
Breakfast Menu services ( another two service Lunch and Dinner Menu are the same they only different in parameters):

```
public class BreakfastMenuServicesImpl implements BreakfastMenuServices {

    @Override
    public BreakfastMenu addMenuItemsToBreakfastMenu(BreakfastMenu breakfastMenu) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem();

        List<MenuItem> menuItemList= breakfastMenu.getMenuItemList();

        if(menuItemList == null){
            menuItemList = new ArrayList<MenuItem>();
        }
        System.out.print("\nInsert food name: ");
        menuItem.setNames(scanner.nextLine());
        System.out.print("Insert food description: ");
        menuItem.setDescription(scanner.nextLine());
        System.out.print("Insert food image: ");
        menuItem.setImage(scanner.nextLine());
        System.out.print("Insert food price:");
        menuItem.setPrice(scanner.nextFloat());

        menuItemList.add(menuItem);
        breakfastMenu.setMenuItemList(menuItemList);
        return breakfastMenu;
    }

    @Override
    public void showBreakFastMenu(BreakfastMenu breakfastMenu) {
        System.out.println("\nBreakfast menu:");
        breakfastMenu.getMenuItemList().forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateBreakfastMenu(BreakfastMenu breakfastMenu) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Insert food want to update:");
        String foodItem = scanner.nextLine();
        breakfastMenu.getMenuItemList().forEach((MenuItem menuItem)->{
            if(menuItem.getNames().equals(foodItem)){
                System.out.print("\nInsert food name: ");
                menuItem.setNames(scanner.nextLine());
                System.out.print("Insert food description: ");
                menuItem.setDescription(scanner.nextLine());
                System.out.print("Insert food image: ");
                menuItem.setImage(scanner.nextLine());
                System.out.print("Insert food price:");
                menuItem.setPrice(scanner.nextFloat());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteBreakfastMenu(BreakfastMenu breakfastMenu) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Insert food want to delete:");
        String foodItem = scanner.nextLine();
        breakfastMenu.getMenuItemList().removeIf(menuItem ->
                                                    menuItem.getNames().equals(foodItem));
    }
}
```

After finishing service, I realize that all the services share the same CRUD process and I can write one father class for model and one father service class for three types of food menu services:

**My new model ( after):**
Food Menu model:

```
public class FoodMenu{
    private BreakfastMenu breakfastMenu;
    private DinnerMenu dinnerMenu;
    private LunchMenu lunchMenu;

    public FoodMenu(BreakfastMenu breakfastMenu, DinnerMenu dinnerMenu, LunchMenu lunchMenu){
        this.breakfastMenu = breakfastMenu;
        this.dinnerMenu = dinnerMenu;
        this.lunchMenu = lunchMenu;
    }
}
```

AbstractMenu model:

```
public class AbstractMenu {
    private List<MenuItem> menuItemList;
    public AbstractMenu(List<MenuItem> menuItemList){
        this.menuItemList = menuItemList;
    }
    public AbstractMenu(){
    }
}
```

Breakfast Menu model:

```
public class BreakfastMenu extends AbstractMenu{
}
```

Lunch Menu model:

```
public class LunchMenu extends AbstractMenu{
}
```

Dinner Menu model:

```
public class DinnerDMenu extends AbstractMenu{
}
```

**My new Service(After)**

AbstractMenuService:

```
public interface AbstractMenuService {
    AbstractMenu addMenuItemsToMenu(AbstractMenu abstractMenu);
    void showMenu(AbstractMenu abstractMenu);
    void updateMenu(AbstractMenu abstractMenu);
    void deleteMenu(AbstractMenu abstractMenu);
}
```

BreakfastMenuService:

```
public interface BreakfastMenuServices extends AbstractMenuService{
}
```

DinnerMenuService:

```
public interface DinnerMenuServices extends AbstractMenuService{

}
```

LunchMenuSerivce:

```
public interface LunchServices extends AbstractMenuService{

}
```

So which one is easier to read and maintain, furthermore, as a result of extending service from father class, all methods in BreakfastMenuImpl requires the override but I don't need to write different methods so I left it's blank. Does this have any negative effects?

My new BreakfastMenuServiceImpl:

```
public class BreakfastMenuServicesImpl implements BreakfastMenuServices {


    @Override
    public AbstractMenu addMenuItemsToMenu(AbstractMenu abstractMenu) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void showMenu(AbstractMenu abstractMenu) {

    }

    @Override
    public void updateMenu(AbstractMenu abstractMenu) {

    }

    @Override
    public void deleteMenu(AbstractMenu abstractMenu) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Your second idea is the right idea, but you didn't go far enough really.  You could just have one "Menu" class and just have it work differently by giving it different names.  The code you list first is fine to turn in, but talk to your instructor about your ideas and see how far you can go.

Comment: Also, code that is working and you just want advice on goes on [codereview.se]